# ArangoDB: how to distinguish insert and update operations from WAL?

Tags: logging, arangodb

See [this link](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/3.6/http/replications-walaccess.html#insert--replace-document-2300)
Insert and update/replace operations have the same  2300 code.
I need to differentiate these two operations. Can someone help me understand this?

Comment: Wouldn't the absence of `data['_rev']` suggest an insert, the presence an update?

Comment: No, '_rev' exists from very beginning.

Comment: Of course; silly me -- wishful thinking...